# Chaining function, stop and continue

Tags: jquery, function

I have some functions that are chaining in a loop. I find the way to stop. My question is how to continue from the point it stopped?

```js
$("#blue").click(one);
 
 $("#stop").click(function() {
  $("#red, #blue, #green").stop(); 
    });
  
 $("#continue").click(function() {//that's the question
  
  
    });
 
 function one(){
  $("#blue").fadeOut(4000, two);
 }
 
 function two(){
  $("#red").fadeIn(4000, three); 
 }
 
 function three(){
  $("#red").fadeOut(4000, four);
 }
 
 function four(){
  $("#blue").fadeIn(4000,one);
 }
```

```css
#stop {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px; left: 50px;
 width:50px; height:30px; line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color:grey;
 cursor:pointer;
}
 
#continue {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px; left: 120px;
 width:100px; height:30px; line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color:grey;
 cursor:pointer;
}

#blue{
 position: absolute;
 top: 150px; left: 150px;
 width:200px; height:200px;
 background-color:blue;
 cursor:pointer;
}

#red{
 position: absolute;
 top:150px; left:150px;
 width:200px; height: 200px;
 background-color:red;
 display:none;
}

#green{
 position: absolute;
 top:150px; left:150px;
 width:200px; height: 200px;
 background-color:green;
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stop">stop</div>
<div id="continue">continue</div>
 
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```

Comment: You can provide a [custom jQuery method](https://github.com/tobia/Pause/blob/master/jquery.pause.js) to pause and resume the animation: the `.stop()` method does not support resuming the animation from its paused state :)

Comment: use `animate` instead: `$('#blue').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 4000, two);` and then queue() and dequeue() functions to stop and resume

Answer (score 1):

Jquery fadeOut / FadeIn / FadeToggle provide a 'progress' option, a function wich can return the remaining time of the duration. Knowing that, plus the element wich is playing and its state (fadeIn or fadeOut), we can tinker something :

```js
// first element will fadeOut
var fadeOut = true;
var count = 0;
var elements = $("#red, #blue, #green");
var remaining = 4000;
var isPlaying = false;



$("#stop").click(function() {
  isPlaying = false;
  $("#red, #blue, #green").stop(); 
});

$("#red, #blue, #green, #continue").click(function() {
  if(!isPlaying){
    fadeElements();
    isPlaying=true;
  }
});
 
function fadeElements(){
  if (fadeOut){
  $(elements[count]).fadeOut({
      duration:remaining,
      progress:function(a,b,c){
        remaining = c;
      },
      complete:function(){
      // when fadeOut is completed we want to fadeIn next element
      (count<elements.length-1)?count++:count=0;
      fadeOut=false;
      remaining=4000;
      fadeElements();
      }
    });
   }else{
     $(elements[count]).fadeIn({
        duration:remaining,
        progress:function(a,b,c){
        remaining = c;
      },

        complete:function(){
      fadeOut=true;
      remaining=4000;
        fadeElements();      
        }
      });

   }
  
 }
```

```css
#stop {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px; left: 50px;
 width:50px; height:30px; line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color:grey;
 cursor:pointer;
}
 
#continue {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px; left: 120px;
 width:100px; height:30px; line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color:grey;
 cursor:pointer;
}

#blue{
 position: absolute;
 top: 150px; left: 150px;
 width:200px; height:200px;
 background-color:blue;
 cursor:pointer;
}

#red{
 position: absolute;
 top:150px; left:150px;
 width:200px; height: 200px;
 background-color:red;
 display:none;
}

#green{
 position: absolute;
 top:150px; left:150px;
 width:200px; height: 200px;
 background-color:green;
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stop">stop</div>
<div id="continue">continue</div>
 
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```

Comment: It's complicated and it only works with fade, but it works!